# python parse html elements while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

well i have a website :

http://www.custojusto.pt/Lisboa?ca=14_s&th=1&q=macbook&cg=0&w=1

and i want to get all the name of the ads and the value for the item in a array, what i have right now is :

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re


listofads = []

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.custojusto.pt/Lisboa?ca=14_s&th=1&q=macbook&cg=0&w=1").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for a in soup.findAll("div", {"class":re.compile("lista")}):
            for i in a:
                c = soup.findAll('h2')
                y = soup.findAll("span", {"class":re.compile("right")})
                listofads.append(c)
                listofads.append(y)


print listofads
```

what i get is something like this :

> ```
>                       </h2>, <h2>
>                           Procura:  Macbook Pro i7, 15'
>
>                       </h2>], [<span class="right">50  &euro;</span>
> ```

which look very bad .... i want to get :

```
Macbook bla bla . price = 500
Macbook B . price = 600
```

and so on

The html of the site is like this :

```
<div class="listofads">
<div class="lista " style="cursor: pointer;">
<div class="lista " style="cursor: pointer;">
<div class="li_image">
<div class="li_desc">
<a href="http://www.custojusto.pt/Lisboa/Laptops/Macbook+pro+15-11018054.htm?xtcr=2&" name="11018054">
<h2> Macbook pro 15 </h2>
</a>
<div class="clear"></div>
<span class="li_date largedate listline"> Informática & Acessórios - Loures </span>
<span class="li_date largedate listline">
</div>
<div class="li_categoria">
<span class="li_price">
<ul>
<li>
<span class="right">1 199 €</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>
<li class="excep"> </li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see i only want the H2 value ( text ) on the div with the class "li_desc" and the price from the span on the class "right" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `BeautifulSoup` as it doesn't support [xpath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but here's how you  could do it nicely with lxml:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

url =  "http://www.custojusto.pt/Lisboa?ca=14_s&th=1&q=macbook&cg=0&w=1"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)

my_products = []
# Here, we harvet all the results into a list of dictionaries, containing the items we want.
for product_result in CSSSelector(u'div.lista')(tree):
    # Now, we can select the children element of each div.lista.
    this_product = {
        u'name': product_result.xpath('div[2]/a/h2'),  # first h2 of the second child div
        u'category': product_result.xpath('div[2]/span[1]'),  # first span of the second child div
        u'price': product_result.xpath('div[3]/span/ul/li[1]/span'),  # Third div, span, ul, first li, span tag.
    }
    print this_product.get(u'name')[0].text
    my_products.append(this_product)

# Let's inspect a product result now:
for product in my_products:
    print u'Product Name: "{0}", costs: "{1}"'.format(
        product.get(u'name')[0].text.replace(u'Procura:', u'').strip() if product.get(u'name') else 'NONAME!',
        product.get(u'price')[0].text.strip() if product.get(u'price') else u'NO PRICE!',
    )
```

And, here's some output:

```
Product Name: "Macbook Pro", costs: "890  €"
Product Name: "Memoria para Macbook Pro", costs: "50  €"
Product Name: "Macbook pro 15", costs: "1 199  €"
Product Name: "Macbook Air 13", costs: "1 450  €"
```

Some items do not contain a price, so results need to be checked before outputting each one.

Comment: that was great its working like a charm i made more functions on that base c0de and a GUI now its a real app :) tnx